# Lucee ORM there is no Session for the datasource

Tags: orm, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to work with ORM in Lucee server but continue to get the error `there is no Session for the datasource [mydatasource]`. The datasource does exist and the connection works, verified in the admin and tested with a cfquery.

Here is the `application.cfc`

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
    <cfset this.datasource = "rift" />
    <cfset this.ormEnabled = true />
    <cfsetting showdebugoutput="false" />
    <cfset this.ormsettings = { } />
    <!---<cfset this.ormsettings.dbcreate = "dropcreate" />--->
    <cfset this.ormsettings.logSQL = true />
    <cfset ORMReload() />
    <cfset testquery = ORMExecuteQuery("from test")>
    <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: Well... what happens if you enable session management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ORMSettings should be defined in the pseudo-constructor, so I believe that is what is causing the issue for you.

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <!--- define orm settings --->
    <cfset this.datasource = "rift" />
    <cfset this.ormEnabled = true />
    <cfset this.ormsettings.logSQL = true />


    <cffunction name="onRequestStart" access="public" returntype="boolean" output="false">
        <cfif StructKeyExists(url, "reload")>
            <!--- you don't want to do this on every request --->
            <cfset ORMReload() />
        </cfif>
        <cfset testquery = ORMExecuteQuery("from test")>
        <cfreturn true />
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Also make sure you have named your cfc `test.cfc` and it's is set to be persistent.

Comment: Haha, didn't even notice that!